# solr wikipedia error in adding the WikipediaTokenizerFactory

Tags: solr, lucene, wikipedia

I am trying to use the `WikipediaTokenizerFactory` http://lucene.apache.org/solr/3_6_0/org/apache/solr/analysis/WikipediaTokenizerFactory.html

But when I start solr I get

```
  {msg=SolrCore 'collection1' is not available due to init failure: Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] fieldType "text": Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] analyzer/filter: Error loading class 'solr.WikipediaTokenizerFactory'.
```

Is this Tokenizer removed in solr 4.5.1, or what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

WikipediaTokenizerFactory is now part of [Lucene repository](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/lucene/analysis/common/src/java/org/apache/lucene/analysis/wikipedia/). You can try using the respective package name.

Note: I haven't used this tokenizer myself, so can't guarantee it would work.